# Spring data couchbase documents java classes inheritance

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

My problem is, that spring data couchbase doesn't search for subclasses of searched class. For example:

Model:

```
@Document 
class A { 
   @Id
   String id 
}

@Document
class B extends A {}
```

And repository:

```
public interface ARepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<A, String>{
     Page<A> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

Spring data couchbase generate query, that has in where condition

> _class="com.example.model.A"

But I want in this query search B documents too. Is some way, how can I do this? When I write own query, I must defining order, limit and offset in query and Pageable is not used. But I want use Pageable.

Comment: Hi Tomas. Did you find a way to do this with Spring Data Couchbase?

Comment: Does my answer there help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636774/where-is-class-built-in-spring-data-couchbase-when-using-findby-methods

Answer (score 1):

Consider generic interface based on inheritance.

Firstly create super class:

```
@Inheritance
public abstract class SuperClass{ 

  @Id
  private int id;
}
```

Then create your subclasses:

```
public class A extends SuperClass { /* ... */ }
public class B extends SuperClass { /* ... */ }
```

Create base repository:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface SuperClassBaseRepository<T extends SuperClass> 
extends PagingAndSortingRepository<T, Integer> { 
     public T findAll();
```

}

And then create SuperClass repository basing on base repo:

```
@Transactional
public interface SuperClassRepository extends SuperClassBaseRepository<SuperClass> { /* ... */ }

@Transactional
public interface ARepository extends SuperClassBaseRepository<A> { /* ... */ }

@Transactional
public interface BRepository extends SuperClassBaseRepository<B> { /* ... */ }
```

SuperClassRepository `findAll()` will search all A and B classes

Comment: Thanks for help, but this is possible only in spring data JPA. Spring data couchbase doesn't have @Inheritance annotation. Is something same in spring data couchbase?

Answer (score 0):

We managed to make this work on Spring Data Couchbase 3.2.12. Here's what we did:

We figured out that mappers for each type were only being created if a repository existed for that type, so, besides our superclass repository...

```java
public interface ARepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<A, String> {
     Page<A> findAll(Pageable pageable);
}
```

We created an empty repository for each of the subtypes such as:

```java
public interface BRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<B, String>{
     // No methods
}
```

The presence of this second repo warranted the existence of an appropriate mapper for `B`, so when `findAll` (or other methods) are invoked in `ARepository`, the mapper for each subclass is present. Having done this, we were able to get a list of `A` that were actually `B` instances.

Hope this helps and nobody has to lose any more time on this. :)